# dynamically changing target of a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, target

I am trying to display my login inside an iframe which loads in the middle of the start page with gray backgroud, however i have a problem dealing with the target of the iframe, things should work as follows:
1- if user logged in successfully home page should load in the parent window
2- if error, error message should be displayed in the iframe itself.

my code:

```
<div id="cover5" onclick="javascript:cover5();">
        <iframe name="warning" src="SignIn.php" id="warning" onclick="javascript:cover5();">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

SignIn.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
  function valid(){
   if(document.getElementById('username').value.toString().length>=1 || document.getElementById('password').value.toString().length>=1){
    return true;
   }
   else{
    alert("The Combination of username and password are Incorrect !");
    return false;
   }
  }
 </script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function ChangeTarget() {
     document.getElementById("login").prop("target", "_parent")
 }
 </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function ChangeText(text) {
                document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML= text;

            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form name="login" id='login' target='_self' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>
<legend>SignIn</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<label for='username' >Email:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='username'  maxlength="50" /> <br />
<label for='password' >Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /> <br />
 <br /> <label id="label1" style="color: red"></label> <br />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Login'/> <br />
<a href='resetPassword1.php'> Forgot/Reset Password? Click Here</a>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

however, the target is not changed by method ChangeTarget() which is called inisde php code, so the problem now is that everything load inside the iframe or everything inside the parent window. anyone knows how to solve the problem?

server side script:

```
mysql_select_db("mydb",$check);
$email = $_POST['email'];  //username that will be submit from a form
$password = $_POST['password'];  //password that will be submit from a form

    // if(mysql_num_rows($temp_privileges_id)== 1) //if the id found that means that the user is already assigned to a conference
   //  {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
             'ChangeTarget();',
             '</script>';
          header('Location: main.php'); // transefer to home page with variable username
     }
```

Comment: The code calling ChangeTarget is server-side? Please provide more details on that part.

Comment: @KevinCollins do i call the function correctly?

Comment: I don't think so because it doesn't look like the form would be rendered again at that point. Try just returning a script block with: `window.top.location.href = "http://www.site.com/main.php";`

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `prop`. Either set the value of the `target` attribute directly

```
document.getElementById("login").target = "_parent";
```

or use `setAttribute`

```
document.getElementById("login").setAttribute("target", "_parent");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.prop()` is a jQuery function.  If you're going to do it in jQuery, do this:

```
$("#login").prop("target", "_parent");
```

If you're not going to do it in jQuery, do it like this in straight JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("login").target = "_parent";
```